# When I am clicking on List view contents, they are opening with web browser not within my application

Tags: android, listview, webview, android-listview

My android app is showing rss feed of my site in a list view. At first my app shows a "loading" page after that latest 20 posts's heading appears in a list view. When I am clicking on the topic name, topic is opening with web browser not within my application.

```
this is my MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

 private MyFeed myRssFeed = null;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  new MyTask().execute();

 }
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
   try {
    URL rssUrl = new URL("http://mywindows8.org/windows-8-tutorials/feed/");
    SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
    MyWindows myRSSHandler = new MyWindows();
    myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
    InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
    myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

    myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed(); 
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
   } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
   } catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
   }

   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   if (myRssFeed!=null)
   {

  ArrayAdapter<Topic> adapter =
          new ArrayAdapter<Topic>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_item,myRssFeed.getList());
    setListAdapter(adapter); 

   }else{

    TextView textEmpty = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    textEmpty.setText("No Feed Found!");
   }

   super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  Uri feedUri = Uri.parse(myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, feedUri);
  startActivity(myIntent);

 }

}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@layout/button5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textColor="#D5D5D5"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@layout/back2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@layout/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:gravity="center"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do 100%, but try to look into extending 'ListActivity' in your activity

Comment: Here list items are showing heading of latest 20 posts of my site... so 20 items are there.. They are parsed from a feed.xml file. So items will be changed dynamically whenever i will publish new content in my site. I want to open the webpages within my app instead of browser when link items are clicked.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

ListView listView = new ListView(this);

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listItemView, int positionOfItem, long idOfItem) {
        // Here you put what you want to do when a listItem is clicked
        Intent k = new Intent(this, Contenturl.class);
                k.putExtra(org.core.mywindows8.Contenturl.URL, "http://mywindows8.org/windows-8-themes/");
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                startActivity(k);

    }
});
```

Further documentation:

- [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)
- [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: @Anik Chakraborty if it helped, you can accept my answer. It will improve your accept rating and will encourage people to answer your future questions.

Comment: Actually here all list view items are the headings of my blog posts, parsed from a xml feed file. So all list view items already have urls.. I just want to create a webview activity which will open the links, within this app, not in web browser, when any of those listview items will be clicked. List view items will keep changing as they show the title of the latest 20 posts of my site. So, there are 20 items in listview, each has different url. How can I implement that? (open the webpages within my app not in browser) Plz help....the site is optimized for mobile view

Comment: You have to use a WebView in your activity. And when you create a listItem, set for the textView that contains an URL a clickListener and start a new Activity with a WebView in it.

Comment: In case of button the url is fixed.. http://mywindows8.org/windows-8-tutorials/ but incase of list view 1st item, 2 nd item ... Etc ate always changing. So how can I implement the url part. As I can not directly put the url as u have shown in ur code...

Comment: Hi, I have added MainActivity.java and corresponding .xml file. Plz have a look... and plz tell me what to do.. I just want to open all list items within my app, not with browser when they are clicked.